# Serving WebP Images to Visitors Using HTML Elements

Tags: webp

Digital Ocean suggests the following format for webp images:

```
<picture>
<source srcset="logo.webp" type="image/webp">
<img src="logo.png" alt="Site Logo">
</picture>
```

In the example below I have applied a class to the jpg. Is it a good idea (or necessary) to apply the same class to the webp? How about adding the alt tag? Do webp images need an alt tag?

```
<picture>
<source srcset="images/pic.webp" type="image/webp">
<img src="images/pic.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt=""> 
</picture>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-and-serve-webp-images-to-speed-up-your-website).

While it's certainly possible to use the picture and source elements, there are reasons against it:

- not supported by all browsers (although it will fall back to the inside img)
- complexifies html code
- requires rewriting of existing code

The alternative option is to use Apache’s mod_rewrite module to automate the process of serving .webp images to supporting browsers (also in the article). The advantages being:

- supported by all browsers
- simpler html
- no need to rewrite existing code

Comment: In the future, I will use mod_rewrite as it does simplify the code. I am assuming this method also affords faster loading times too.

Comment: @ControlZ for easy conversion of existing images to webp, I've created [webp8](https://github.com/8ctopus/webp8). You may want to check it out.